# Scope[String] dynamic function doesn't update in front

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope

I'm working in angularJS + laravel aplication, I'm trying to update some scope from a dynamic function like this:

```
$scope.closeoverlay = function (){
   argumentsArray = [].slice.apply(arguments);
   for (var i = 0; i < argumentsArray.length; i++) {
       console.log($scope[argumentsArray[i]]);
       $scope[argumentsArray[i]] = ''
       console.log($scope[argumentsArray[i]]);

   }
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<p>{{var1 ? var2+'-'+var3:'Nothing set'}}</p>
<div>
 <input type="radio" id="var3" name="var3" ng-model="var3" value="1" >
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="var1" ng-model="var1" format="number" >
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="var1" ng-model="var2" format="number" >
 <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-red" ng-click="closeoverlay('var1','var2','var3')">
  Cancel
 </button>
</div>
```

I have to use dynamic scope because there are around 4 - 5 cancel with different vars.

Main problem is if I console vars it work well, but in front they just don't update, I make some test with apply, but always I get `$apply already in progress`, I think I'm doing it wrong. (I also try with `angular.foreach` but it doesn't work either)

Answer (score 0):

just declare the variables in the controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.var1=1;
    $scope.var2=2;
    $scope.var3=3;
    $scope.closeoverlay = function (){
       argumentsArray = [].slice.apply(arguments);
       for (var i = 0; i < argumentsArray.length; i++) {
           console.log($scope[argumentsArray[i]]);
           $scope[argumentsArray[i]] = ''
           console.log($scope[argumentsArray[i]]);
       }
    }
});
```

and the result for my example is: 2-3 Cancel

Comment: Actually it works at console, but front still doesn't update scope.

Comment: Have you selected a best answer?